# Who's the earliest rock band to use a sitar?

Tags: history, bands

Who's the earliest rock band to use a sitar on a song recording or album?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source [wikipedia article 'Raga rock'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raga_rock)

Dates are release dates.

Actual first appears to be the Beatles: "Norwegian Wood": December 1965.

but it followed a time of many musicians being interested in Indian music, influenced by [Ravi Shankar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravi_Shankar) who toured Europe and the USA in the late 1950s and early 1960s, sharing a record label with [the Byrds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Byrds). David Crosby (with The Byrds at that time), brought the music to the attention of George Harrison.

Influenced :- using sitar-like sound on guitar or similar, see the wiki article for more detail

```
Davey Graham: "She moved through the fair" 1963
Yardbirds: "Heart full of soul" : June 1965 : influenced, demos used sitar
Kinks : "See my friends" : July 1965, imitated the sound with guitar
```

Comment: Thanks! I listen to a lot of psychedelic music from the 60's on ward, but I was just curious if there was anything before then. I will probably mark you as the answer in a couple of days, if no one else finds anything else!

Comment: It's an interesting question, glad you asked it, as I thought until I dug into the subject that maybe the Incredible String band might have been first, but clearly not